# Why don't I get the option of upgrading to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 19.10, 20.04

I'm on 19.10. It has been days since 20.04 came out, how long before 
those on 19.10 get offered to upgrade???

Answer (score 0):

From terminal, attempt to upgrade to Focal:

```
sudo apt update&&sudo apt upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

If your PC doesn't find the upgrade use the -d flag:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```